# Is it possible to send binary data to make a AZTEC barcode in the Google Wallet API?

Tags: json, binary-data, google-pay, android-pay

I am currently using the Google Wallet API to make Google Wallet Passes and I need to use binary data to make the AZTEC barcode work. From what I know, it's not possible to put binary data in a JSON and encoding the binary data to Base64 also did not work. This is because the system I have to make Google Wallet Passes for doesn't accept encoded data, only binary data.

Furthermore, when I send the JSON to Google to make a pass, the encoded binary data doesn't decode (I can't tell it to decode after Google receives the JSON for as far as I know). Is there a way around this or is it possible to use binary data in the barcode of the Google Wallet Pass somehow?

I tried putting the encoded binary data in the 'value' parameter under the 'barcode' parameter. I expected it to give me back a string of that exact encoded binary data, which it did.

I also tried to put decoded binary data directly into the 'value' parameter, although that doesn't work as well, because it's put into a JSON and JSONs can't contain raw binary data.

Thanks in advance!